# How to fix "App Store Connect Operation ERROR ITMS-90771"

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to submit my app to TestFlight, but I keep getting this error.

[image]

and this is what I have in my `info.plist`

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you checked background mode in target capabilities?

Comment: Are you using background processing?  If not then remove the Capability. If you are then you need to add the identifier your are using when you create your background processing task as per the answer

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you so much. I had the background processing checked without noticing. I turned it off and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 196):

Add this in your info.plist and then resubmit your app

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
</array>
```

or if you use more than one BGTask then use this code

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>com.yourCompanyName.appName1</string>
    <string>com.yourCompanyName.appName2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: do i change the com.your... to my bundle ID?

Comment: Yes, But if you add more then one then add unique String on the end of your bundle id.

Comment: I found that adding this does in fact fix the issue, but in xCode when you open your project page, the Info.plist file gets re-set/re-written without these value. A bit annoying

Answer (score 76):

### Or Even Better:

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
</array>
```

Best

Comment: This is a really good answer. I don't want to vote it up though.

Comment: god help me for im about to upvote

Answer (score 40):

As it says you need to add "BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers" to your info.plist. You have turned on background task capabilities for your app but did not add corresponding identifiers.

1. Goto your Info.plist file. Hover over any item + button will be highlighted. Click on it to add a new item.
2. Copy and paste "BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers" under the Information Property List column. This will create an array in the Type column.
3. Click the add button on the item you just created to add background task identifiers for the array.
4. Note that it is recommended by apple to mention task background task identifier in reverse domain notation(com.something.name).

In the end, it will look like this,

[image: info plist image]

For more info, you can refer to this Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler).

Comment: so i added BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers. But what about item 0 and 1? do i need to add my bundle name only?

Comment: You just need to give one id for each background task you performing. It should be like com.yourCompanyName.appName that is it.

Comment: @MustafaAljaburi thanks so match, it works for me and you get my vote

Comment: It works, but today you only need to add  $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) on the right column.

Answer (score 10):

Actually I had to do both of these:

### 1.First change your info.plist for the related target.

1. Right Click on your info.plist
2. Open As
3. Source Code
4. Add Following Key lines to the file after main `<dict>` tag.

```xml
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
</array>
```

[image]

### 2.Second change it from the Target info view

1. Go to your project target
2. Click on `Info` tab
3. Check if you can see the `Permitted Background Task Scheduler Identifier` Array type. if you cannot find it, add it using `+` on a unexpanded menu on the list.
4. Then expand it > mark should be shown to down direction like in the screenshot. and Then click `+` on the `Permitted Background Task Scheduler Identifier`. Make sure its mark is expanded (down chevron). And it will add an item with String Type, and add your bundle ID there... or add `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)` so it will take the bundle identifier automatically.

make sure to use proper bundle identifier convention as mentioned in other answers well.

Thanks for all who have response to this question before, I found them very helpful.

[image]

Comment: The second step might be necessary. I have a project with several targets. After I changed the info.plist as the 1st step for them, one of the target doesn't add the "Permitted Background Task Scheduler Identifier" automatically. So I had to do it as in the 2nd step here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Add "BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers" to "info.plist" by paying attention to a few points.

1. Open info.plist file
2. Add "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers" below the "Information Property List".(Using add (+) button)

[Add "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6AFk.png)

3. Add a new item below "Permitted background task scheduler identifiers".
   (Make sure the arrow is pointing down i mean, it is not like that ">")

[Add a new item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x34uZ.png)

4. Enter your bundleID as a value.