# Firebase Plugins not Working on IOS (Ionic)

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am developing an Ionic App, and I am having some issues with the IOS App and Firebase/FCM Plugins.

---

The **Android App** is working perfectly with the below plugins installed:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

---

As for the **IOS App** I tried several Plugins and none is working:

> Option 1:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

The app is building successfully, but it is failing when launched on an iPhone. When debugging, I am getting this error Message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Configuration fails. It may be caused by an invalid GOOGLE_APP_ID in GoogleService-Info.plist or set in the customized options.'
```

> Option 2:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

When building with this plugin, I am getting the below error in xCode:

```
** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        CompileC /Users/walid/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Nutripro-aabwvacmftjwnefthwnyidfyxswx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Nutripro/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Nutripro.build/Release-iphoneos/Nutripro.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FCMPlugin.o /Users/walid/Documents/www/nutripro/platforms/ios/Nutripro/Plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/FCMPlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I searched alot to find a solution for this error, and I can't find any.

> Option 3:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
npm install @ionic-native/firebase
```

I can build an App successfully using this plugin, and I can run it on my iPhone and a Token is generated and I can receive Push Notifications Normally.
But the problem here is happening when Uploading the App to the App Store

- Archiving on xCode is Successful
- When Distributing/Uploading the App, I am getting the below Error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90771: "Missing Info.plist value. The Info.plist key 'BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers' must contain a list of identifiers used to submit and handle tasks when 'UIBackgroundModes' has a value of 'processing'. For more information, refer to the Information Property List Key Reference at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html."
```

I searched the Internet and found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927881/how-to-fix-app-store-connect-operation-error-itms-90771) stating that I must add the below to my info.plist file

```
<key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>com.nutripro.mobile</string>
</array>
```

After adding it and Resubmitting my Application, I am getting an email back from Apple

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "NutriPro" 1.1.11 (1.1.11). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Best regards,

The App Store Team
```

If I remove the plugin, the App is being uploaded and approved.

The weird thing is that the documentation on @ionic-native/firebase says that they got rid of the UIWebView and are using WKWebView

---

**N.B: After Each Option, I am uninstalling the installed Package and Node Module, and I am deleting the platforms folder.**

Do you guys have any idea how I can fix this issue? I've been trying to figure out a solution for almost 1 week and I can't find any!

Comment: I don't know who Voted -1. But when you do, please add a comment telling why u voted -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research and unsuccessful attempts, I found a solution.

For Android, I am using [fcm-with-dependecy-updated](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
npm install @ionic-native/fcm
```

For IOS, I am using [firebase-messaging](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-messaging)

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-messaging
```

Comment: Did you got your App approved after implementing this solution in your project?

Comment: Yes it was approved after this Solution

Comment: Sorry mates, I am having an issue when adding this plugin. 

Installing "cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging" for ios
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 5.1.1, failed version requirement: >=6.0.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging' for ios.

my question is, if I update cordova to 6, can i will continue compiling IONIC V3 or i will have the ons of errors that ionic gave us as gifts?.

thanks you.

Comment: example of ionic nightmare.

cordova platform add ios@6.0.0 --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@6.0.0
Adding ios project...
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ios not supported.)

Comment: U should read ionic v3 documentation and see if it supports cordova 6.
If not, I recommend (if ur project is not very big) to upgrade ur ionic version.

Comment: Not sure I understand how you're using cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated for android and cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging for ios.  How do you specify a particular plugin will only use a specific platform?

Comment: @D.Hodges. I have my master branch which is the latest updated branch and I clone all my branches from it. It has the conf that I use locally.
Then I created 2 new branches "master_android" and "master_ios". Each has separate plugins conf. After testing, I merge my branch to all 3 master branches.

This is not a typical solution, but I don't have a lot of updates on the mobile app and for now I am good with this solution

Comment: @MarioRawady thanks a lot...that worked for me for Android and iOS actually.  I don't see much documenation on cordova-plugin-firebase-messaging as I do for cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated.  Are you able to get notifications when the app is closed?  Which method do you use, if so?

Comment: Hello I am having the same problem, cannot understand how to solve it... I have everything (iOS and Android) in the same project, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

> rm -rf platforms/android

> cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase

**Install this plugin firebase-lib**

*For cordova-cli >= 9.x.x && (cordava-ios >= 5.0.1 || cordava-android >= 8.x.x). Use the latest major releases just by running:*

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib

*For cordova-cli <= 8.1.1 && (cordava-ios <= 4.5.5 || cordova-android >= 8.x.x) Use the v4.x release by running:*

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@4.1.0 --save

*For cordova-cli <= 7.1.0 && (cordava-ios <= 4.5.5 || cordova-android <= 7.1.4). Run the following in your terminal:*

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-lib@3.3.0 --save

**Androidx**

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

**For cocoaPods**

> If you are building your app using Xcode, please open platform/ios/my-cordova-project.xcworkspace instead of platform/ios/my-cordova-project.xcodeproj so that the Xcode can load both Cordova app & the Pods.
> Your repo needs to be up to date. To keep it up to date, run pod repo update anywhere in your terminal.